# Unexpected token: BACKUP in statement

Tags: backup, hsqldb, database-backups

I'm having a problem while trying to make an online backup in a HSQLDB database:

I'm using this rc file:

```
urlid pentaho
url jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/hibernate
username PENTAHO_USER
password whatever
```

And this command line:

```
java -jar ..\data\lib\hsqldb-1.8.0.jar --rcFile conn.rc pentaho
```

Once connected, I try to execute the backup command as per the manual:

```
BACKUP DATABASE TO './' BLOCKING;
```

But all I get is this error message:

```
SQL Error at 'stdin' line 1:
"BACKUP DATABASE TO './' BLOCKING"
Unexpected token: BACKUP in statement [BACKUP]
```

The question is: does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BACKUP command is not supported by older versions of HSQLDB. Use version 2.2.9 instead of 1.8.0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to test that later.